# How do I wait for user input when opening a alert dialog in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-alertdialog, ui-thread

Okay, so I wrote this code, where I use a thread to open some alert dialogs. The problem is that the thread doesn't wait for the first dialog to close before opening the second dialog. As you can see in the code I used `wait()` between opening the two dialogs and use`notify()` in the onClick events of the buttons in the dialogs. I use the `runOnUidThread()` function to show the created dialogs. For some reason, when I open the activity the dialogs won't open and the app will have a black screen and the app will eventualy stop working. When I comment out the `wait()` statements (including the try and catch statements), the activity shows both the alert dialogs after each other. So is it even possible to wait for user input like this? Or  am I doing something completly wrong. Thank you. HEre is my code :

```
public class EditTagActivity extends Activity
{   
    AlertDialog alertDialog1, alertDialog2;

    Thread dialogManager = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(showDialog1);
            try 
            {
                synchronized(dialogManager)
                {
                    Log.d("Threads", "wait()");
                    dialogManager.wait();
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(showDialog2);
            try 
            {
                synchronized(dialogManager)
                {
                    Log.d("Threads", "wait()");
                    dialogManager.wait();
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     };

    Thread showDialog1 = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Log.d("Threads", "alertDialog1.show();");
            alertDialog1.show();            
        }
    };

    Thread showDialog2 = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Log.d("Threads", "alertDialog2.show();");
            alertDialog2.show();            
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_tag);
        Log.d("Threads", "setup()");
        setup();
    }

    void setup() 
    {
        Log.d("Threads", "g.run()");
        createAlertDialog();
        dialogManager.run();
    }

    void createAlertDialog() 
    {
        Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Alert");
        alert.setMessage("Flaq");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                synchronized(dialogManager)
                {
                    dialogManager.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                synchronized(dialogManager)
                {
                    dialogManager.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });
        alertDialog1 = alert.create();
        alertDialog2 = alert.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: The right way it to avoid `Thread`. It's almost always "wrong" to use on Android since there are better abstractions for concurrency and there are lots of tools to schedule events to happen in the future in the main thread. Hint: just put `showDialog2` in `onClick` of Dialog1. No thread required.

Comment: Why are you using threads? Isnt it possible to just show the second dialog from the onClick-method from the first dialog?

Comment: Thanks for you quick respons. @zapl so what kind of tools are you talking about?

Comment: @Michael I think this would be possible, but I'm not sure if this solution will be very efficient in my program, but I will think about it!

Comment: Why shouldnt it be efficient? its as efficient as it can get :)

Comment: Yes it is efficient if you would have only two or three alert dialogs opening in the same order everytime. But that is not the case in the application I want to make ;-)

Comment: Android's main / ui thread is an [Event Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), you can inject events (`Message` / `Runnable`) via `Handler`. Pretty much everything in android uses that to post messages to the ui thread either from the ui thread or from some background thread (that's how async task gets the result from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`). So I'm talking about `Handler`, directly based on that [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), to some extend even `AsyncTask`, .. you'll find it in use all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just call the dialog.show() of the second dialog in the onClick of the first dialog's setPositiveButton. This way the second dialog will be forced to wait until the first one is dismissed.

Comment: So the conclusion is is that my way isn't possible at all or am I doing something completly wrong?

Comment: your way is possible, but it is wrong to use threading for such minor tasks.

Comment: Okay. So what am I doing wrong then or how would you do it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using threads to wait for user input? A dialog has to be run on the UI-thread as stated in the android training guide: "*Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View objects; this thread is called the UI thread.*"

A dialog will occupy the UI-thread until it is dismissed. On close you can process the user input on a background thread.

Here are some good references:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
void createAlertDialog() 
    {
        Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Alert");
        alert.setMessage("Flaq");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                       /* 
                       Handle user input on other thread. With for example AsyncTask 
                       */
                       alertDialog2 = alert.create();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                /* 
                Handle user input on other thread. With for example AsyncTask 
                */
            }
        });
        alertDialog1 = alert.create();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the references. As you can see in my code. I show the dialogs on the ui-thread, with the runOnUiThread() function. I know what the ui-thread is and that you should definetly not block it. I think I use the wait statement in a wrong way, but I don't know the right way.